# sshd server: match a subdomain name of a client and not just IP of that client

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

using openssh 9.2

for security I am using match to restrict clients who may access the ssh server

```
Match Address 10.0.0.30
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

this works fine but since this client machine may change its IP I want the SSH server to "lookup" the IP address.  like so

```
Match Address myclient.mydomain.net
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

That subdomain is available via DNS such that on that ssh server if you do a `nslookup` of `myclient.mydomain.net` it reports `10.0.0.30`.

**Sadly this doesn't work :(. So does openssh even support such a DNS lookup and if so what is the syntax?**   I tried the `Host` match but I think that refers to ssh server Host.  There is also a `RDomain` match but that doesn't work as I would like either.

the manual isn't helping me.

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html

```
     Match   Introduces a conditional block.  If all of the criteria on
             the Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following
             lines override those set in the global section of the
             config file, until either another Match line or the end of
             the file.  If a keyword appears in multiple Match blocks
             that are satisfied, only the first instance of the keyword
             is applied.

             The arguments to Match are one or more criteria-pattern
             pairs or the single token All which matches all criteria.
             The available criteria are User, Group, Host, LocalAddress,
             LocalPort, RDomain, and Address (with RDomain representing
             the rdomain(4) on which the connection was received).

             The match patterns may consist of single entries or comma-
             separated lists and may use the wildcard and negation
             operators described in the PATTERNS section of
             ssh_config(5).
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this approach can work. It's unsafe as IP addresses
can change faster than DNS does, but also might not be feasible to
implement.

I would suggest to just setup key-based authentication,
disable password authentication, and not worry about IP addresses.

Provided you keep your secret key a secret, this will be completely secure.

If you need information about key-based authentication for the
openssh server, you may find that a lot exists on the internet.
A random example is the article
[How To Configure SSH Key-Based Authentication on a Linux Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server).

Comment: Yes I already have that setup.   I agree it's completely secure but without some IP match I will get hackers hammering on that port.   This is a admin computer for the LAN.  Mostly I access it via a VPN no problem but if the VPN is down I need to NAT through the router directly which exposes it to internet.  Further since my public IP is not static (my ISP may change it) I could potentially loose access to that admin computer in that case.  Looks like I'll have to run a script that changes the ip in the conf file and restarts the ssh server.  not a biggy just thought openss would support it.